# Ubuntu 17.10 works very slowly

Tags: performance, 17.10, nvidia-geforce

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 today, and it's working very slowly compared to Ubuntu 16.04 or Windows 10. This appears especially when I open the Dash (the animation of the Dash is buggy and does not respond quickly).
I have a desktop PC with 4GB RAM, 1.6 dual core processor and an Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT integrated card.

I have installed the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver and logged in to Ubuntu with Xorg, but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

Laggy and buggy Dash performance could be caused by a either a buggy upgrade from an earlier Ubuntu release or by installing Ubuntu 17.10 when it was still in alpha or beta and then upgrading it after Ubuntu 17.10 was officially released.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, i have login by ubuntu on Xorg  but nothing has changed

Comment: it is installed and i selected  the nvidia driver and nothing has changed.

Comment: same issue here, it also takes more than 20m to shut down

Comment: Since installing 17.10 three days ago, my high-spec laptop has been reduced to feel like a cheapy. This was a clean install.  :-(